# Complex iloc logic given a string of index range slices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a str that looks like this:

```
paired_str = '[3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977]'
```

these are slices of index ranges that I want to pass through an iloc logic to call from a dataframe. The goal is to essentially use this and make a plot that specially plot data from those index ranges in paired_str.

What I have tried so far:

```
paired_ranges = df.iloc[np.r_[paired_str]]
```

However this gives an error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3584: 71943'
```

The part that I do not understand is if I manually type in the ranges it works fine, ie:

```
paired_ranges = df.iloc[np.r[3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977]
```

However, I would like to do this programmatically as there will be hundreds of these range slices list. I have tried many different ways with no success, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you so much for reading!

Note: I would like to plot it out like so once its working:
Example with seaborn:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=paired_ranges, x=var1, y=var2, size = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just replace code with a string representation of your code.
A string has no meaning for python, it first needs to be parsed to be usable as code. In your case you're trying to make a list of [`slice()` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) (note that `a:b` is just syntactic sugar for `slice(a,b)`), but you only provide a string. So we need to convert that string into a list of slice objects, for instance like so:

```
paired_str = '[3584: 71943, 74593: 78252, 79205: 85318, 86152: 92030, 93207: 96977]'
paired_ints = (map(int, pair.split(':')) for pair in paired_str[1:-1].split(','))
slices = tuple(*map(lambda start_stop: slice(*start_stop), paired_ints))
```

Now the slice-objects in `slices` can actually be used for indexing.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've learned a lot from your respond and this makes a lot of sense!

My issue now is when I try to pass the slices variable into the 
paired_ranges = df.iloc[np.r_[slices]]

I get a error since it needs to take a string and not slice object

Comment: I actually just figured it out I used tuple and it passed it through successfully! Thank you again!

paired_ranges =df.iloc[np.r_[tuple(slices)]]

Comment: Yes, having using multiple indices is equivalent to passing them as a tuple. I'll update the snippet accordingly.